# Always treat a ForeignKey field like it was in raw_id_fields in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

This scenario happens way too often in my project:

- someone adds a model `Foo` that has several `ForeignKey` fields, one of them to refers to model `Bar`
- an admin is added for that model (and works OK)
- the code is deployed
- on production server, `Bar` has millions of instances
- someone accesses `Foo`'s admin page; Django tries to retrieve all `Bar`s at once (to display them in a combo box) and the server gets overloaded
- later the problem gets fixed by editing `Foo`'s admin and adding `bar` to `raw_id_fields`.

I'd like to prevent this situation from happening in the future, preferably by somehow stating (once and for all) that `Bar` has many rows and it should be *always* treated as if the field referring to it was listed in `raw_id_fields` in all admin pages. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is an excelent point. This is a **critical** issue that can turn down the database and even the web server.

Considering this, I believe the default approach MUST be the `raw_id_fields` thing. If you know what you are doing, then you change this behavior.

Unfortunately, most of the authors of the admin interfaces libraries disagree of this thought. Not just for Python-Django, but also for other communities like Ruby-Rails.

5 years ago I got tired having the same problem, then I developed the [django-smart-autoregister](https://github.com/paulocheque/django-smart-autoregister), that do this and also auto configure using another good patterns. Even today I face this problem, so I guess it is worth to take a look.

ps: the library was originally implemented using a modular approach, though you just call some functions that will configure the `raw_id_fields` for you according to the model field.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> ForeignKey is represented by django.forms.ModelChoiceField, which is a
>   ChoiceField whose choices are a model QuerySet.

ModelChoiceField extends Field, and therefor has a widget property that can be abused
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L49

Add this somewhere in your project files.

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import ForeignKeyRawIdWidget
ModelChoiceField.widget = ForeignKeyRawIdWidget
```

downside: this is also going to happen on non-admin forms

Comment: Hmm, that's a nice starting point- now maybe one could make ModelAdmin use that widget selectively when creating its ModelForm.